# How do I toggle a .setAttribute?

Tags: javascript, html, image, class, toggle

I know there’s a .toggle for things like toggling a class, but for this specifically, I can’t do that it seems. I’m trying to toggle an image from a moon to sun (light and dark theme).

I’ve gotten a function that, when an anchor tag is clicked, it will change from a moon to a sun, but I can’t manage to figure out how to make it toggle.

If I can’t use .toggle, then what do I use? Do I possibly need to create my own function using Javascript logic? Are there scripts that do this already?

The Javascript Code:

```
function changeTheme() {  
  document.getElementById("theme").setAttribute("src", "sun.png"); 
}
```

The HTML Code:

```
<img onclick="changeTheme()" src="moon.png" id="theme" class="toggle-theme">
```

(*The class is in there for the actual theme change...*)

**Thanks for any answers!**

*Note: This is my first post on Stack Overflow. If I did something wrong or you need more information, please, do tell me. Thank you.*

Comment: just check my answer, provided few suggestions so that you won't fall in the loop as I was when I write the switch theme functionality code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just suggestions as it helped me allot during creating the theme-switch, use the 
`HTML attribute property` to keep track of them.

**Never ever write conditions based on the image name or source it makes your code dependable and it's not a good way of programming.**

Tracking of CSS is very important when you have to switch the theme of your website

```js
function changeTheme() {
  const domRef = document.getElementById("theme");

  if (domRef.getAttribute("data-theme-name") === "dark") {
    domRef.setAttribute("data-theme-name", "light");
    domRef.setAttribute("src",
    "https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/50/000000/adobe-photoshop.png");
  } else {
    domRef.setAttribute("data-theme-name", "dark");
    domRef.setAttribute("src","https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/50/000000/adobe-animate.png");
  }
}
```

```css
.toggle-theme {
   height: 15vh;
   
}
```

```html
   <img onclick="changeTheme()" 
    data-theme-name="dark"
    src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/50/000000/adobe-animate.png" id="theme" class="toggle-theme">
```